# Why is it possible to declare properties with a string as identifier? What's under the hood when doing it?

Tags: javascript

I've been using properties with hyphens in their names(IDs) for a while now because they come pretty handy when setting HTML tag properties with the same name.

In **JavaScript** we do:

```
var obj = {'prop-with-hyphen': true}; // ✓

obj['prop-with-hyphen'] = true; // ✓
```

How does this work?

Comment: What is the precedent for *not* allowing strings as object keys?

Comment: "Why is it possible to declare variables with a hyphen on them?" — It isn't. You said so in the body of the question.

Comment: "What other languages out there share this behaviour?" — Probably lots. Shopping questions are off-topic.

Comment: Think about it, how would you subtract things if the hyphen *(minus sign)* could be used in variable names and object keys, or anywhere you think it's convenient.

Comment: Objects are meant to store potentially large sets of data with with a very wide variety of names that are sometime not known ahead of time. Variables are specific labels for data that are relevant only to the developer(s) working on the code. They're inherently different and there's little compelling reason to add more complex syntax for variables in order to accommodate a wider variety of names..

Comment: You can however use more than just ASCII letters for variables, if that helps. `var 世 = "world"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because what you're doing when you declare `obj` is creating a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), something JS (like many languages) has as a native construct. Basically, you're setting a string key and then referring to it later. Since the key is a string, it can be composed of any characters you want. `var obj = {'78*(^&%&*#^$)I*(FG*)(&^': "FOO!"};` is perfectly valid (though why you'd want a key like that, I have no idea).

As has been pointed out in the comments in your original question, using hyphens in variable names would make the subtraction operator (`-`) rather troublesome to use.